# Can a Carto web map auto-pan to follow point animation?

Tags: carto, animation

Setting up an animated map in Carto Builder that follows a point across the Pacific. In order to see local route details the map must be scaled in, but then not all of the route is visible at once. Can Carto auto-pan to follow animations?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't, really. In Carto Builder, you can set parameters for center_lat, center_lon, and zoom once in the URL of the map. To automatically change the extent, you'll need to use cartoJS instead. This means rebuilding your map from scratch. Then you have control of extent using the `.setBounds()` method.

See: https://carto.com/developers/carto-js/reference/